# Find and replace with CGI script

Tags: bash, replace, cgi

I'm trying to use a CGI script to run a find and replace command on a specific text file.

I currently have a CGI script (foo.sh) which then executes a non-CGI shell script (bar.sh).  In the non-CGI shell script (bar.sh), I'm able to perform a number of simple bash commands such as wget, mkdir and cd, and I'm also able to execute a .js file with the standard dot-slash bash syntax.

However, I can't get any find and replace commands to work when executed with CGI.  I've tried sed, awk and perl, all of which work perfectly when used either directly on the command line or if I execute bar.sh from the command line.  But once I try to execute the CGI script from the browser, the find and replace commands no longer work.

The syntax I've tried is below.  Any suggestions appreciated.

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' text.txt

{ rm text.txt && awk '{gsub("foo", "bar", $0); print}' > text.txt; } < text.txt

perl -p -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' text.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure your script is operating in the correct directory for the local file path used there?

Comment: Thanks Etan.  Yes, I'm actually specifying the directory of the text file from the root level.  The file path in my initial question was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

just a few thoughts:

- if run by the web server, the script will probably be executed as a different user which could lead to permission-related problems.
- maybe the awk/sed etc. commands are not in the path used by the web server process (try to use an absolute path here as well)
- is there anything in the web server's error log?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input Michael, and sorry for the late response.  You were correct in that it was a permissions issue caused by the fact that the CGI script runs not as me but as the "www-data" user.

The problem occurred because that user didn't have write privileges to execute a sed find and replace command on the target folder (in this case a directory within /usr/share/).

I changed permissions on the target folder to full read/write everyone, and now the script runs successfully.

Thanks again.